# Errors while migrating an ASP.NET MVC project from Javascript to Typescript

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I am trying to add Typescript support to an ASP.NET MVC project. So I changed the extension of all the .js files to .ts and added the tsconfig.json file to the project.

When building, Typescript gives thousands of errors, mostly in the form of "Property x does not exist on type {}" and does not generate the corresponding .ts files. In Javascript, it is OK to write `var a = {};` and then later on dynamically add properties to it. And since Typescript is a superset of Javascript, I would expect this kind of valid Javascript to be OK for Typescript, too.

So, is there a way (such as a tsconfig.json configuration parameter) for Typescript to ignore these as errors and generate the .ts files from .js files?

Comment: _IMHO_, you'd be better off if you use `ts` for Typescript and leave your js as they were. You'll get suggestions here on "disabling" such, but then it sort of defeats the purpose of **Type**script. Also unsure what you mean by "generate ts files", it doesn't, ts transpiles to vanilla JS.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Errors while migrating from Javascript To Typescript in an ASP.NET MVC project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54620923/errors-while-migrating-from-javascript-to-typescript-in-an-asp-net-mvc-project)