# Errors while migrating from Javascript To Typescript in an ASP.NET MVC project

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, typescript

I am migrating js files to ts in an ASP.NET project. There are js libraries in the project such as Handlebars. And they include code like this:

```
function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
    module.exports = factory();
else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
    define([], factory);
else if(typeof exports === 'object')
    exports["Handlebars"] = factory();
else
    root["Handlebars"] = factory();
```

I have two questions regarding this:

1. Should I be converting these library files to ts too? If I do, I get errors indicating that exports, define, module cannot be found. How should I proceed here?
2. Regardless of these files being ts or js, js code that is now converted to ts is using these libraries. And speaking of the example above, they cannot find and recognize "Handlebars" as a variable defined on `window`. What can be done about this?